# Have C generate an error inside a _Generic

Tags: c, generics, macros, c11

I've been working on some code (related to linear algebra). I have a number of types that one should be able to multiply with each other.

Naturally I thought "let's use _Generic" for this. Well it works, as long as the combination of argument types are valid. According to search engines, some libraries have resorted to using attributes on dummy functions to generate errors:

```
#include "stdio.h"

// Example struct.
typedef struct mat3_s
{
    float m[9];
} mat3;

// Dummy function.
mat3 mult(mat3 const *A, mat3 const *B)
{   
    return *A;
}

mat3 mults(mat3 const *A, float const *B)
{
    return *A;
}

typedef mat3 (*dummyptr)(void *A, void *B);
extern dummyptr INCOMPATIBLE_TYPES() __attribute__((error("Crikey"))); 

#define LMULT(A, B)\
    _Generic((A),\
    mat3: \
        _Generic((B),\
            mat3: mult, \
            float: mults, \
            default: INCOMPATIBLE_TYPES()),\
    default: INCOMPATIBLE_TYPES()) (&(A), &(B))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mat3 a = {{0}};
    mat3 b = {{0}};
    mat3 c = LMULT(a, b);

    mat3 d = LMULT(a, "not kosher");

    // Inhibit GCC from optimising away above variables.
    printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    return 0;
}
```

The gymnastics involved is the "INCOMPATIBLE_TYPES" function. As it stands it doesn't work well (if at all). And it is GCC only, and fragile, and... just not nice.

`_Pragma("gcc error \"Great heavens\"")` will not work either since GCC expands `_Pragma` to the resulting macro. And that happens to be inside a `_Generic`-expression which of course is processed at a later stage.

I am about to give up and just give gibberish back (also called C++ error reporting) and hopefully it will give enough information as to what might be the problem.

Does anybody else have any ideas how to generate a user friendly enough message if two types are passed for which there is no corresponding function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for your example the solution is quite simple, leave out the `default` parts. The compiler will then produce an error that the type doesn't match.

Comment: Oh,... it's that simple? *Applies desk to own forhead* Why didn't I try that first...

Comment: I'm a bit miffed it doesn't take the "switch" into account before evaluating arguments though. For example `LMULT(a, 2)` complains about `&` being applied to a literal 2 even though the `_Generic` expression will be invalid anyway because it didn't match the types. But it complains BEFORE it discovers that "hey, this pattern match failed". Oh well.

Comment: @Skurmedel, yes, as would be for an `if (1) .... else ....` all path in a `_Generic` must be valid.

Comment: Yeah, but in a way that's a bit sad, because it is a really weak form of matching. Requiring ALL contexts to be equally valid even though their prerequisite is another type severly limits the amount of applications But that's my whine for the C-standard team. _Generic is still pretty nice. Could've been just a bit nicer though.

Comment: The variant they had in mind is to have function pointers as the different choices. There the validity of the branches is simple. The other thing, to have "rogue" branches is not very is to specify. You'd have to be sure that the expressions are at least syntactically valid, otherwise you wouldn't find the end of these expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I hope they expand on it in future standards. I like C11 a lot, and making macros better is very welcome.